# Function not getting executed inside map in pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, promise, observable

_filter function is not getting executed from map which is running inside a pipe.
I am trying to  populate the autocomplete inputs in the form.. all the autocompletes are getting populated with the same values("HRI_620", "HRI_912" and so on). I need them to get populated by their respective values.

Here's the code snippet:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addReviewForm = this.fb.group({
      Review_Name: ['', Validators.required],
      Item_Type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Sub_Project_ID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      CRH_Number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Hierarchy_Indicator: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Review_Date: ['', Validators.required],
      Author: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Reviewer: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });



this.filteredHRIOptions  =  this.populateAutoComplete(this.addReviewForm, "Hierarchy_Indicator",["HRI_620", "HRI_912","HRI_624", "HRI_903", "HRI_817"]);
this.filteredAuthorOptions  =  this.populateAutoComplete(this.addReviewForm, "Author", ["ABC", "DVB", "DFG"]);
this.filteredReviewerOptions  =  this.populateAutoComplete(this.addReviewForm, "Reviewer", ["ABH", "SHB"]);

   
  }
populateAutoComplete(form: FormGroup, control, valuesToPopulate){
    this.filteredOptions = form.controls[control].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map( value =>this._filter(value, valuesToPopulate))
    );
  }
  private _filter(value: string, valuesToPopulate ): string[] {
    const filterValue = this._normalizeValue(value);
    return valuesToPopulate.filter(item => this._normalizeValue(item).includes(filterValue));
  }

  private _normalizeValue(value: string): string {
    return value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
  }
```

The _filter function( inside map) only runs once after populateAutoComplete function has run thrice.

Comment: Do you subscribe to that `valueChanges` function somewhere?

Comment: was going to say...you have to subscribe to an observable for it to be executed

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe, like this:

```
this.filteredOptions = form.controls.control.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this._filter(value, valuesToPopulate))
).subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // TODO: Logic
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    // TODO: Handle error
  },
});
```